# How does the identity function $id_X$ imply injectivity of the right inverse function of the composition $g \circ f$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f: X \rightarrow Y$,
$g: Y \rightarrow X$,
$g \circ f = id_X$

I can see, graphically, how having $f(x) = f(x')$ with $x \neq x'$ would mean that $f(x)$ (or $f(x')$ for that matter) would have to map from and to two values of X, which would disqualify it from being a proper function. It is therefore imperative for $f$ to be injective. How can the injectivity of $f$ be proven with help from its composition/identity function **without** relying on drawings or graphical methods? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $x,y\in X$, according to the given hypothesis, we conclude that

\begin{align*}
f(x) = f(y) & \Longrightarrow g(f(x)) = g(f(y))\\\\
& \Longrightarrow (g\circ f)(x) = (g\circ f)(y)\\\\
& \Longrightarrow i_{X}(x) = i_{X}(y)\\\\
& \Longrightarrow x = y
\end{align*}

Thus $f$ is injective, as desired.

**BONUS**

The proposed result also holds when the composition $g\circ f$, defined based on $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$, is only injective. The proof is essentially the same.

Besides it, the following statement is also true:

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$. If $g\circ f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective. Indeed, one has that
\begin{align*}
Z = (g\circ f)(X) = g(f(X)) \subseteq g(Y)
\end{align*}
since $g(Y) \subseteq Z$, we conclude that $g(Y) = Z$, from whence $g$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! Would this also prove that the identity implies the injectivity of $f$? 
$$x=x'$$
$$\implies id_X(x)=id_X(x')$$
$$\implies g\circ f(x)=g\circ f(x')$$
$$\implies g(f(x))=g(f(x'))$$
$$\implies f(x)=f(x')$$
$$\implies x=x'$$

Comment: Perhaps you are misinterpreting the definition of injectivity. We say that a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is injective if $f(x) = f(y)$ implies that $x = y$, for every $x,y\in X$. Alternatively, we can restate it as follows: $f$ is injective if $x\neq y$ implies that $f(x)\neq f(y)$ for every pair $x,y\in X$. Did it help?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was only wondering if it's ok or right to formalize the implication into something like $$g \circ f = id_X \implies f inj$$ and try to get a proof starting only from the identity or $x,x'$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. You now have to prove $x=y$ (this is one way of stating the definition of injectivity). My hint to you is apply $g$ to both sides.